# Can't download Microsoft malware removal tool

Tags: windows-8, malware, uefi

It seems that my computer has malware that prevents me from visiting https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/security/pc-security/malware-removal.aspx

I tried reinstalling Windows 8 and it doesn't help. Is it possible that malware is using UEFI to infect the installer? If so, what are my options?

Comment: **If you reinstalled Windows 8 then its not malware preventing the download.**

Comment: Have you tried to vist http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/malicious-software-removal-tool-details.aspx by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound, yeah, it works. Strangely, even after activating Windows (which I forgot to do the first time), configuring time zone, removing misconfigured router from the equation (which enabled Windows Update for me), I still can't load the page in the OP (its loading process keeps restarting). I can load it from Linux, though. Why might this be the case?

Comment: Could be any number of things including a bad dns route

Comment: @Ramhound, I know that if it kept giving me 302 Found, the browser would complain after five hops, so it's either a javascript redirect, or something else entirely.

Comment: I should point out the website was VERY SLOW when I attempted to vist it.

Comment: @Ramhound, new turn of events: in Linux, Chrome has the same behavior as in Windows (frantically refreshing the page before it's even loaded), but Firefox loads it just fine. I don't even know what's going on anymore :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ashamed to say that it was my own router pulling tricks on me. **Edit:** googling revealed that dd-wrt's "Block ActiveX" feature actually blocks too much, including Windows Update. Unticking it solved my problem.

P.S.: I also found out that I can burn verified UEFI version from the motherboard manufacturer onto a CD and then flash it on boot, enable secure boot and then reinstall Windows again. This is as close as I can get to setting everything to factory defaults, so in theory it should take care of most UEFI malware. I'll do that unless I get satisfactory answer to why the link in the OP isn't working (its downloading process keeps restarting, which *looks* like something malware would do).

Answer (score 0):

You could try physically removing the hard drive from your computer. Plug it into another machine that doesn't use UEFI, and try running a virus scan from that machine.

Or, if you Google around, you'll find that you can disable Secure Booting without disabling UEFI, which should make it easier to boot from virtually any rescue disk out there, and hopefully clear up this infection.

Comment: The author would only need to disable Windows 8 if they were attempting boot to another operating locate on same disk as Windows 8.  The author can change the boot order of his devices without having to disable secure boot.